# What the different of array object and common array in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php code to select some data from mysql. I use jquery to execute that php code like this :

```
var first = $.get("<?php echo base_url() . 'control_closing/getKomentarMD/' ?>", function(data) {
        first = initializedFirstComment(data); // Initialized first current comment
        console.log(first);

    });
```

it gives me return like this in firebug :

```
GET http://localhost/portal/control_closing/getKomentarMD/ 200 OK 47ms  

    [{"id_request":"001","comment_bapak":"Mohon kepada pihak IT, selalu laporkan ke saya tentang fast item...<br>"},
     {"id_request":"002","comment_bapak":null},
     {"id_request":"003","comment_bapak":null},
     {"id_request":"005","comment_bapak":null},
     {"id_request":"008","comment_bapak":null},
     {"id_request":"009","comment_bapak":"Test aja<br>"},
     {"id_request":"010","comment_bapak":null},
     {"id_request":"011","comment_bapak":"Ini adalah tempat MD menuliskan komentarnya....<br>"},
     {"id_request":"012","comment_bapak":null}
    ]
```

But, when I use like this, :

```
$.ajax({
     url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'control_closing/getKomentarMD/' ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(second) {
                console.log(second);

            }
        });
```

It gives me like this on firebug :

```
POST http://localhost/portal/control_closing/getKomentarMD/ 200 OK  52ms    


[Object { id_request="001",  comment_bapak="Mohon kepada pihak IT, s...entang fast item...<br>"}, 
 Object { id_request="002",  comment_bapak=null}, 
 Object { id_request="003",  comment_bapak=null}, 
 Object { id_request="005",  comment_bapak=null}, 
 Object { id_request="008",  comment_bapak=null}, 
 Object { id_request="009",  comment_bapak="Test aja<br>"}, 
 Object { id_request="010",  comment_bapak=null}, 
 Object { id_request="011",  comment_bapak="Ini adalah tempat MD men...kan komentarnya....<br>"}, 
 Object { id_request="012",  comment_bapak=null}
]
```

Is it different result ? 
I use this, because I want to compare those array.

**Update**

Okey, I choose to use the second choice : **object**. Now,
Can give me a hand to make the first array is like second array ?
Thanks for all the response, it so appreciated.

Comment: Both arrays are filled with objects, the second one is simply parsed as a JSON object. You would use both arrays in almost the same way.

Comment: @user3054852 that is incorrect, the first example cant be chained in the same way the second example can, but the second example can be used in the same way as the first example can be used.

Comment: @jimmyjansen You are absolutely correct, I was a bit hasty writing my comment

Answer (score 0):

The difference can be found in how to access the different data.

In the first example you have to use the string as identifier, in the second you dont have to use the string:

**first example**

```
first["id_request"] //returns "001"
```

**second example**

```
second.id_request //returns "001"
```

---

In more complex situations I personally prefer the second result because you can chain them `data.days.monday` for example, where this becomes a bit messier in the first example.

Both can be used though and its a matter of personal preference

Answer (score 0):

It is globally the same result. FireFox `Object` is informative.

To answer your question, the difference between **common array** and **objects array** has no sense. There is only **Array**:

`I_am_an_array = [something, something2, ...]`

`something` can be a string, a number, an Object...

`{"ok":"44", "ko":"hello"}` is an Object String Notation, a way to write object, a `JSON` (Javascript Object Notation).

---

`fool_array = [4,654,1.4, "hello", {"name":"john", "address":"malkovitch street"}, 4.42456343, "i dont want an iwatch", 999]`

```
[{"id_request":"001","comment_bapak":"Mohon kepada pihak IT, selalu laporkan ke saya tentang fast item...<br>"},
     {"id_request":"002","comment_bapak":null},
     {"id_request":"003","comment_bapak":null},
     {"id_request":"005","comment_bapak":null},
     {"id_request":"008","comment_bapak":null},
     {"id_request":"009","comment_bapak":"Test aja<br>"},
     {"id_request":"010","comment_bapak":null},
     {"id_request":"011","comment_bapak":"Ini adalah tempat MD menuliskan komentarnya....<br>"},
     {"id_request":"012","comment_bapak":null}
    ]
```

is an array of Objects:

```
foreach(obj in yourArrayOfObjects){
     console.log(obj.id_request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have no `MIME` type (`application/json`) set on the server side for the data being returned. Hence, one notable difference between the first and second example is the `type` of the data returned from the server. The first one is of type `string` and second one is of type `object`. `$.get()` determines the default data type based on the `MIME` type of the data being returned when the type is not explicitly mentioned as the 3rd argument (in your case). Hence the data is not parsed as an object for you to access like `first.id_request` or `first[“id_request”]`. You’d have to manually parse it using `$.parseJSON(first)` for you to be able to access the properties.

In your second example, you’ve explicitly mentioned the `dataType` as `json`, which means, jQuery automatically parses the data returned for you to access without having to parse manually like the first example.

So, you could use either of the following (they are the same!).

```
$.get("<?php echo base_url(); ?>control_closing/getKomentarMD/", function(data) {

    console.log(data);

}, 'json'); //note the 3rd argument as the data type

// ----------------------------------------

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>control_closing/getKomentarMD/",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Note: `$.get()` is simply a wrapper around `$.ajax()`. Hence, you’d be better off using `$.ajax()` which is more readable and provides more options.